# mod_rewrite truncating the URL before rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cfm?urlparam=/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

urlparam only ever returns the first two parameters after the domain

i.e if i type

www.blahblah.com/competitions/display/competition01/

and then write the contents of urlparam i only ever get /competitions/display/

Can anyone mke any suggestions mod rewrite is a bit of a black art to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `REQUEST_URI` variable instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.cfm?urlparam=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```